# What is a correct word for a teacher who gives additional lessons to young students?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Most teachers just teach a classroom in something like mathematics, geography or grammar. However, there are also teachers who give **additional** lessons to a single student or a small number of students.

An example situation could be a teenager who is working really hard to get nice grades for mathematics but he is failing all the time. He needs extra lessons to succeed which can be helpful in some situations.

Is there a nice word for such a teacher and a word for teaching such lessons? In Dutch, there is a word "bijlesleraar" where "bijles" means "additional lessons" and "leraar" means "teacher". An obvious translation could be "additional lessons teacher". [However, when searching on linkedin](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:linkedin.com%20%22additional%20lessons%20teacher%22&start=10), only Dutch people seem to have this profession.....

So it is likely to be an incorrect term, translated from Dutch to English literally.

So what is a good term for an "additional lessons teacher"? Is there also a nice term for teaching such additional lessons?

Comment: That person is called a "tutor".

Comment: dangit @KristinaLopez! Ten seconds. Just ten! :-(

Comment: Ha Ha @MattGutting! That's usually me being just a few seconds too late!

Comment: The additional lessons themselves are often called __supplementary__ lessons. Lessons which cover the basics or prerequisites of the course (which a student should generally already know) are called __remedial__ lessons.

Comment: According to [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tutor) the Dutch equivalent is *privéleraar*

Comment: @Mari-Lou. Disagree. A "priveleraar" can also give lessons that are not supplementary but just for a single person. It is highly unusual and extremely expensive but it happens.

Comment: Then that person is still a teacher.  A tutor can be a *private teacher*, it needn't be [one-to-one](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/one-to-one_1?showCookiePolicy=true) either, students can come in pairs if they are both at the same age and level.

Comment: Interesting @Mari-LouA...I never heard of a priveleraar.

Comment: You may refer to such lessons by the expression **private tutoring** and to the professor by **private tutor**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kristina and Matt: Thanks.
"Tutor" is indeed the word:
http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tutor

It does not seem to be specific for one country:
https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:linkedin.com+%22tutor+*+mathematics%22+germany

Comment: Could you include the dictionary's definition in your answer, please? The best answers are self contained etc..etc.. :)